# CTE table ...using a CASE Statement to fill it

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and trying to run 3 separate statements in a CTE.

Something like:

```
WITH C1 AS
(
    if (@Param = 1)
      SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableA
    else if (@Param = 2)
      SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableB
    else
      SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableC
),
C2 AS
  Select xxxxx
```

But it's NOT compiling.

Is that something possible??

Comment: possible duplicate of [if else within CTE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907344/if-else-within-cte)

Comment: @RegisteredUser ..yes it seems like a duplicate. Thanks for passing the link, it gives very interesting answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your `Select` for the CTE to work like this:

```
WITH C1 AS
(

      SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableA WHERE @Param = 1
    UNION ALL 
      SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableB  WHERE @Param = 2
    UNION ALL
      SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableC WHERE @Param <> 1 and @Param <> 2
),
C2 AS
  Select xxxxx
```

Comment: Interesting ...I'll try that !!

Comment: Assuming the select is way more complex, would there be a performance hit running the Union All, ..or SQL is clever enough to know that @Param is the 1st thing to check ??

Comment: I don't know the answer, give it a try. In general though, I've found that using temp tables in place of CTE's often provides a significant increase in query speed. I'm sure there are counter examples, but that's been my experience.

Answer (score 1):

No, common table expressions do not support if else blocks.  Common table expressions are basically inline views.