# How to manage my query for different condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working and trying to manage my query according to these conditions

1. All Stations, All Statuses
2. All Station, Specific Status
3. Specific Station, All Statuses
4. Specific Station, Specific Status

Note: in my stored procedure, `0` denotes All, All Station = 0, All statuses = 0

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectFineIssuanceAll_Sp]
  @StatusID smallint,
  @StationID smallint,
  @FromDate smalldatetime,
  @ToDate smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN
    Begin Try
       If(@StatusID = 0) --if all statuses
       Begin 
           If(@StationID = 0)    --if all stations and statuses
               Begin
                   Select 
                        dbo.Web_Users.Name as UserName, Issuance.Vehicles.VehicleID,
                        dbo.VehicleTypes.VehicleType, Issuance.LTOperator.LTName,
                        dbo.Stations.StationName, dbo.Statuses.Status 
                   from 
                        Issuance.FineIssuance
                   Inner Join 
                        dbo.Web_Users ON Issuance.FineIssuance.User_ID = dbo.Web_Users.UserID
                   Inner Join 
                        dbo.Statuses ON dbo.Statuses.StatusID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Status_ID
                   Inner Join 
                        Issuance.Vehicles ON Issuance.Vehicles.VehicleID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Vehicle_ID
                   Inner Join 
                        VehicleTypes ON dbo.VehicleTypes.VehicleTypeID = Issuance.FineIssuance.VehicleType_ID
                   Inner Join 
                        Issuance.LTOperator ON Issuance.LTOperator.LTID = Issuance.FineIssuance.LTOperator_ID
                   Inner Join 
                        dbo.Stations ON dbo.Stations.StationID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Station_ID
                   Where 
                        Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime >=  CONVERT(smalldatetime, @FromDate)
                        AND Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime <= CONVERT(smalldatetime, @ToDate)

               End  -- if all stations and statuses
           Else
               Begin -- else all statuses and specific station

                   Select dbo.Web_Users.Name as UserName, Issuance.Vehicles.VehicleID,
                   dbo.VehicleTypes.VehicleType, Issuance.LTOperator.LTName,
                   dbo.Stations.StationName, dbo.Statuses.Status from Issuance.FineIssuance
                   Inner Join dbo.Web_Users
                   ON Issuance.FineIssuance.User_ID = dbo.Web_Users.UserID
                   Inner Join dbo.Statuses
                   ON dbo.Statuses.StatusID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Status_ID
                   Inner Join Issuance.Vehicles 
                   ON Issuance.Vehicles.VehicleID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Vehicle_ID
                   Inner Join VehicleTypes
                   ON dbo.VehicleTypes.VehicleTypeID = Issuance.FineIssuance.VehicleType_ID
                   Inner Join Issuance.LTOperator
                   ON Issuance.LTOperator.LTID = Issuance.FineIssuance.LTOperator_ID
                   Inner Join dbo.Stations
                   ON dbo.Stations.StationID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Station_ID
                   Where dbo.Stations.StationID = @StationID
                   AND Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime >=  CONVERT(smalldatetime, @FromDate)
                   AND Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime <= CONVERT(smalldatetime, @ToDate)

               End --else all statuses and specific station
       End -- if all statuses
       Else
           Begin --specific station and status

               Select dbo.Web_Users.Name as UserName, Issuance.Vehicles.VehicleID,
               dbo.VehicleTypes.VehicleType, Issuance.LTOperator.LTName,
               dbo.Stations.StationName, dbo.Statuses.Status from Issuance.FineIssuance
               Inner Join dbo.Web_Users
               ON Issuance.FineIssuance.User_ID = dbo.Web_Users.UserID
               Inner Join dbo.Statuses
               ON dbo.Statuses.StatusID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Status_ID
               Inner Join Issuance.Vehicles 
               ON Issuance.Vehicles.VehicleID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Vehicle_ID
               Inner Join VehicleTypes
               ON dbo.VehicleTypes.VehicleTypeID = Issuance.FineIssuance.VehicleType_ID
               Inner Join Issuance.LTOperator
               ON Issuance.LTOperator.LTID = Issuance.FineIssuance.LTOperator_ID
               Inner Join dbo.Stations
               ON dbo.Stations.StationID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Station_ID
               Where dbo.Stations.StationID = @StationID
               AND dbo.Statuses.StatusID = @StatusID
               AND Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime >=  CONVERT(smalldatetime, @FromDate)
               AND Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime <= CONVERT(smalldatetime, @ToDate)

           End
   End Try

   Begin Catch
        Select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrMsg
   End Catch

END
```

Please help me in managing it, I have tackled many conditions but having hard time tackling more, I can't manage it further for other conditions, please help

Comment: So what's the question? Where are you stuck? some sample data... some sample output or desired output. or some error. what is it?

Comment: i can't manage it further for other conditions, please help

Comment: is the above one working for the given parameters?

Comment: yes but i have to display different data on each condition

Comment: You're going to need to specify `OPTION RECOMPILE`, or [use different techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907344/if-else-within-cte/2907356#2907356).  Often, you can do this type of thing with some (fairly) simple dynamic SQL.  Side note - you [really want to use exclusive upper bounds](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) with date/time/timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using multiple `IF / ELSE` blocks you can achieve the same thing using such `WHERE` conditions:

```
WHERE (@StationID = 0 OR dbo.Stations.StationID = @StationID)
    AND (@StatusID = 0 OR dbo.Statuses.StatusID = @StatusID)
    AND Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime >=  CONVERT(smalldatetime, @FromDate)
    AND Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime <= CONVERT(smalldatetime, @ToDate)
```

Comment: exactly what i was about to suggest.

Comment: The procedure will need `OPTION RECOMPILE` or parameter sniffing is going to have some bad effects.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of entire query. (remove all if and else)
just write below query in TRY Block

```
Select dbo.Web_Users.Name as UserName, Issuance.Vehicles.VehicleID,
 dbo.VehicleTypes.VehicleType, Issuance.LTOperator.LTName,
 dbo.Stations.StationName, dbo.Statuses.Status from Issuance.FineIssuance
 Inner Join dbo.Web_Users
 ON Issuance.FineIssuance.User_ID = dbo.Web_Users.UserID
 Inner Join dbo.Statuses
 ON dbo.Statuses.StatusID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Status_ID
 Inner Join Issuance.Vehicles 
 ON Issuance.Vehicles.VehicleID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Vehicle_ID
 Inner Join VehicleTypes
 ON dbo.VehicleTypes.VehicleTypeID = Issuance.FineIssuance.VehicleType_ID
 Inner Join Issuance.LTOperator
 ON Issuance.LTOperator.LTID = Issuance.FineIssuance.LTOperator_ID
 Inner Join dbo.Stations
 ON dbo.Stations.StationID = Issuance.FineIssuance.Station_ID
 Where 
(@StationID = 0 OR dbo.Stations.StationID = @StationID)
AND (@StatusID = 0 OR dbo.Statuses.StatusID = @StatusID)
AND Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime >=  CONVERT(smalldatetime, @FromDate)
AND Issuance.FineIssuance.IssuanceDateTime <= CONVERT(smalldatetime, @ToDate)
```

Comment: i have to display different data on each condition

Comment: but your code shows same data even in different conditional blocks. where is this different data you want to show?

Comment: somehwere i pass specific parameter and somehwere i eliminate parameter